# JavaScript not updating value from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, thymeleaf

I have a small problem. This is my HTML code fragment:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="boiler : ${boilers}">
        <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].model}"></td>
        <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].brand}">
        <td th:text="${#lists.size(boiler.value)}"></td>
        <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].price}"></td>
        <td>
            <form>
                <input type="text" th:class="boiler_model" th:id="boiler_model"
                       th:value="${boiler.value[0].model}" style="width:75px;"/>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="quantity" style="width: 80px"/>
            </form>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_submit" th:text="Add">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn_submit').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
        // var boilerModel = $(".boiler_model").val();
        var boilerModel = document.getElementById('boiler_model').value;
        if (quantity === 0) {
            alert("You must fill the quantity");
        }
        else if ($.trim(boilerModel) === "") {
            alert("You must choose the model");
        }
        else {
            var productIds = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/order",
                data: {quantity: quantity, model: boilerModel},
                success: function (data) {
                    window.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My problem is when I click the button it does read the quantity, but only reads the first model, even though it is printed in input correctly. I even removed the "hidden" type so I could see it for myself.
[image]

As you can see - the input is printed correctly, but when I debug this the controller always receives a quantity that is null if clicked on 2nd or 3rd model, but correct for the first one and model that is always the same. It always is "Super Hot Premium".

Could you please help me modify the table so it reads input separately from each row and then sends it to my controller?

Thank you very much.

Comment: apart the issue related to unique ids you may consider to change this lien **$("#quantity").val()** to **$(this).closest('tr').find(".quantity").val()**. In any case change the same id with a class name! If you can try to avoid multiple forms because you are using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code :

- you are looping through your `boilers` collection and generating a row for each loop. Each row contains two input fields with the same ids : `quantity` and `boiler_model`
- in your click event handler, you are not looping through each row to submit data.

To fix this :

- Follow [this example](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) to keep track of your loop status
- Use the row index to generate unique ids for both your input fields
- Store the size of your boilers collection in some hidden field to be able to send data from all rows
- In your event handler, retrieve the size of your boilers collection and retrieve/send data for each row.

Here is a suggestion for your template (please note that I haven't tested it) :

```
<tr th:each="boiler, iterStatus : ${boilers}">
    <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].model}"></td>
    <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].brand}">
    <td th:text="${#lists.size(boiler.value)}"></td>
    <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].price}"></td>
    <td>
        <form>
            <input type="text" th:class="boiler_model" id="boiler_model_${iterStatus.index}"
                   th:value="${boiler.value[0].model}" style="width:75px;"/>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="quantity_${iterStatus.index}" style="width: 80px"/>
        </form>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_submit" th:text="Add">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" id="boilersLength" th:value="${#lists.size(boilers)}"/>
```

And your event handler :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn_submit').on("click", function (e) {
        var quantity, boilerModel, boilersLength, i;
        e.preventDefault();

        // retrieving the length of the boilers collection
        boilersLength = $("#boilersLength").val();

        // looping and sending data for each row : 
        for (i=0;i<boilersLength;i++) {

            // retrieving data from both inputs : 
            quantity = $("#quantity_" + i).val();
            boilerModel = $("#boiler_model_" + i).val();

            if (quantity === 0) {
                alert("You must fill the quantity");
            }
            else if ($.trim(boilerModel) === "") {
                alert("You must choose the model");
            }
            else {
                var productIds = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/order",
                    data: {quantity: quantity, model: boilerModel},
                    success: function (data) {
                        // I wouldn't reload the window here, or you may reload before all data is sent 
                        // window.reload();
                    }
                });
            }       
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to the way you suggest, but it didn't change a thing - still the same problem.

Comment: What doesn't work? It must have changed something. Do the input fields have unique ids? Is there the right value in the boilersLength input field? Does your event handler try to send data for each row? etc.

Comment: Okay, I changed id to th:id and it worked. Thank you. Is there a way to clean the input after clicking on the Add button? Because with the iterative solution it adds the previous record as wel if the input is not cleared.

Comment: In your event handler, you can probably empty the input fields value with `$("#quantity_" + i).val("");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a **unique-id to identify on which Row the button is clicked** so that you could get those values on your controller on the basis of that **'unique-id'**

For Example :--

```
<tr th:each="boiler : ${boilers}">
                   <td th:text="${boiler.uniqueID}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].model}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].brand}">
                    <td th:text="${#lists.size(boiler.value)}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${boiler.value[0].price}"></td>


                  //Rest of your Code

<td>
<button type="submit" th:onclick="'javascript:addFunction(\'' + ${boiler.uniqueID} +'\');'" >Add</button>
</td>
</tr>
```